# How to share an Individual Apple iOS Developer Account

Tags: ios, code-signing, iphone-developer-program

I looked through other StackOverFlow questions, but I'm a little confused.
I'm trying to share a iOS Developer Account with my trusted friend.
he has his own apple id, but we have input my apple id in his mac too just to stay sure.

then we followed a tutorial to import the .p12 certificate key, downloaded and imported in Xcode the provisioning profiles ecc but he still gets the "valid signing identity not found" message..

we know that is not a 100% safe practice but sharing this account is the most comfortable solution for both of us.

Comment: What about the .pem key have you added .pem key in you system

Comment: There is no need to give your account details in the developer account you can invite your friend and keep him in admin position so that he can also access as Agent level resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be at least 2 files you need to import in Keychain:
- development certificate
- distribution certificate
Also, not sure, but it might help:
- the original self-signed certificate you submitted to apple (the CSR)

The certificates need to be generated from the computer that originally signed the CSR and imported in the second computer's keychain.
Also, be sure to import the certificates in the login keychain.

ps. close XCode before importing the certificates - or close/restart after importing.

Answer (score 0):

Another very simple approach, i can confirm working (if you don't want to give the apple id password of "Person A" to another "Person B"):

- Share the screen of "Person B"'s Mac to "Person A" (the one with the developer account's apple id login credentials), eg. via messages App on your Mac
- Allow "Person A" to remotely control "Person B"'s Mac screen
- Let "Person B" enter the login credentials for the apple id associated to the developer account directly within XCODE (Settings >> Accounts).
- On "Person A"'s Mac: Export his/her apple id account information (Settings >> Accounts >> Gear Icon) and send the file to "Person B".

  - On "Person B"'s Mac: Import the file when promted after trying to run a build on an attached device ("Person A" might have to enter a password, again).

Steps might also work in different order (eg. importing the profile first), but i didn't test that.